# ASP.NET Core web app in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and created new ASP.NET Core web app project with .NET 7.0 framework, but after creating project, while viewing solution explorer there is no templates of ASP.NET application, I am confused

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGW7F.png)

I installed .NET 7.0 and Visual Studio 2022, in Visual Studio I installed 3 workloads - ASP.NET & web development, Azure development, .NET desktop development. I cloned new Azure repos in to my local. I created new project in Visual Studio 2022 by choosing "ASP.NET Core web app (razor pages)" and given project name, location of cloned repos and selected .NET 7.0 framework and after project creation there was no templates in solution explorer, its just a blank blue interface

Comment: It's confusing here. You wanted to open a cloned repo or create a new solution/project?

Comment: open a cloned repo

Comment: Have you tried go to the cloned repo and open the .sln file?

Comment: That's the issue: ``I created new project`` you don't need to create new project, just go to your cloned repo and look for ``*.sln`` or ``*.csproj``

Comment: yes *.sln and *.csproj files are there, I opened visual studio from my cloned repo by using "open with visual studio" so it's there, but I don't able to click start debugging option in visual studio.  there is a green play button on top right, its showing select startup item